# How to renewcommand the word-size in section titles?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I type `\section{\Large Section title}` to make the section title larger than what it originally appears. Please could you tell me how to achieve this effect by redefining the command `\section` uniformly, so that to larger the word-size in the section titles?

Comment: If you use KOMA-classes, you can use `\setkomafont{section}{\Large}` in your preamble.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I am using the classical `amsart` class.

Comment: @kwgl: Redefining the `\section` command is tedious, since there is a `\section*` version too, and the `\section[]{}` version as well.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Well, thanks for sharing your opinion. It was a technical question that my friends preferred making the titles more distinguished from the contexts artificially.

Comment: @kwgl: Wait some minutes please, I will provide a small solution ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, `amsart` has no support for `\section[]{}`, so it is not really necessary to define that, but for later uses perhaps;-)

It is not a good idea to add something like `\section{\Large My sophisticated Title}, since this leads to a large text entry on the TOC, which looks awkward.

In my opinion, both section title and the number should be scaled if `\large` etc. is applied, so I put the font change in `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair within the redefinition.

The actual font change is done in the `\sectionstartuphook` command, however, other commands can be put there as well.

If the tradiditional `\section` is requested, either call a copy, i.e. `\LaTeXStandardSection` as usual or say `\let\section\LaTeXStandardSection`, however, this will destruct the earlier redefined version. The first method is used for the 3rd section in the example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}



\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section%


\newcommand{\sectionstartuphook}{\LARGE}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unstarredsection@@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredsection@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection@@opt}[2][]{%
\begingroup%
\sectionstartuphook%
\LaTeXStandardSection[#1]{#2}%
\endgroup%
}%


\newcommand{\starredsection}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\sectionstartuphook%
\LaTeXStandardSection*{#1}%
\endgroup%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredsection@@opt}{\unstarredsection@@noopt}%
}%

\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifstar{\starredsection}{\unstarredsection}%
}%




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\blindtext
\clearpage
\section*{Two}
\blindtext
\clearpage

\LaTeXStandardSection{Three}%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christian! Now I got understood why you said it is "tedious". The code helps us!

Comment: It's much easier with `titlesec`…

Comment: @Bernard `titlesec` is not compatible with AMS document classes.

Comment: @Bernard: I would agree with you, but see Gonzalo Medina's comment

Comment: `\section` in `amsart` is defined via `\@startsection` so it *does* have support for the *-form and the optional argument.

Comment: Why not simply redefine `\section` as defined in `amsart.cls`? Here's the necessary redefinition: (the only change is adding `\Large`): `\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\Large\scshape\centering}}
\makeatother`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I was too lazy to look inside `amsart.cls`, that's the sad, but quick answer :D

Answer (score 3):

It's actually quite easy (although I don't like it). The `amsart` class uses the standard `\@startsection` command, so it's just copying the relevant code from `amsart.cls` and adding `\large` where necessary. Oh, and `\Large` is really too much.

I changed also `\specialsection` and `\contentsnamefont` for uniformity.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\large\centering}}% added \large
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\large\scshape\centering}}% added \large
\renewcommand\contentsnamefont{\large\scshape}% added \large
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\blindtext

\section{Preliminary results}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be nitpicking: it's not exactly the standard (as in the one in the kernel) `\@startsection`, since `amsart` defines its own version.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Well, the idea is just the same, isn't it? The changes are about putting starred section in the table of contents anyway and they don't affect the meaning of the arguments to `\@startsection`.

Comment: Of course it's the same; I didn't say otherwise, did I?

Comment: @egreg: I appreciate your solution, but does `\section[shorttitle]{longtitle}` really work? I tried with non-redefined sections from `amsart.cls` and it does not work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Of course it works. However, the AMS classes don't use the short title in the TOC (which was a wrong decision by the standard classes), but just for the headers, if such headers appear, of course.

Comment: @egreg: Ok, I just meant for the TOC, not for column headers.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If you want a different version of the title for the TOC, you use `\for{toc}` or `\except{toc}`.

Comment: @egreg: I just wondered about the different behaviour of `\section` in `amsart.cls` compared to standard classes. I am fine with it.